# Is using <meta name="distribution" content="global"> still valid or of no use nowadays?

Tags: web, seo, blogs, meta-tags

Many search engines are not using ***meta keywords*** and Google through many recent updates has suggested on not using ***meta refresh*** etc.

Is using `<meta name="distribution" content="global">` or on page-to-page basis for various countries, still valid or it's of no use now?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta tag distribution defines the level or degree of distribution of your webpage and how it should be classified in relation to methods of distribution on the world wide web. There are currently only three forms of distribution supported by the distribution tag:

- Global - indicates that your webpage is intended for everyone
- Local - intended for local distribution of your document
- IU - Internal Use, not intended for public distribution

Personally I never had used it. In Google webmaster tools I just set the target country and that's it. I have a page or set of pages that are not intended for public distribution I just make sure to make them password protected.

I will assume that If Google don't find one It will act as if the content distribution was set as global, but to be honest with you that is just an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

"distribution" is not a recognized metadata name. See http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions

I'd say it's of no use unless it's of use to you internally for some reason.